# No target "flutter_pos_printer_platform_image_3_plugin"

Tags: flutter, windows, printing, desktop

I got the following error when I ran desktop windows app:

```
CMake Error:
  Error evaluating generator expression:

    $<TARGET_FILE:flutter_pos_printer_platform_image_3_plugin>

  No target "flutter_pos_printer_platform_image_3_plugin"


CMake Error:
  Error evaluating generator expression:

    $<TARGET_FILE:flutter_pos_printer_platform_image_3_plugin>

  No target "flutter_pos_printer_platform_image_3_plugin"


CMake Error:
  Error evaluating generator expression:

    $<TARGET_FILE:flutter_pos_printer_platform_image_3_plugin>

  No target "flutter_pos_printer_platform_image_3_plugin"


CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
Exception: Unable to generate build files
```

I use this package:

```
flutter_pos_printer_platform_image_3: ^1.1.2
```

the app runs perfectly before using this package.

I want to run the flutter app on windows 11

Comment: Did you update the package to version 1.1.2, or did you introduce the package (used it for the first time) to your app?